# Get CPU used (Max) and CPU used (Avg) in Azure SQL Elastic Pool

Tags: powershell, t-sql, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, azure-elasticpool

I want to get get "CPU used (Max)" and "CPU used (Avg)" from the Portal using a SQL Query or Powershell script. I used "sys.elastic_pool_resource_stats", but did not mentioned details.

Is there any way to do this, using SQL Query.

Below is the sample screenshot. From the below screenshot I want to get CPU used (Max): 1.94 and CPU used (Avg): 0.07. This data is for Last 1 month.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Baxy, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are many third-party tools or community scripts (that use T-SQL or PowerShell) that enable you to monitor performance of your database. Most of them use CPU utilization as one of the fundamental metrics. As an example, you can use [Get-DbaCpuUsage](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Get-DbaCpuUsage) command from PsDba tools PowerShell library to monitor CPU usage using the following PowerShell:

```
Get-DbaCpuUsage -SqlInstance sql2017
```

You can also use custom scripts  and libraries like the [Query Performance Insights](https://github.com/JocaPC/qpi) library that enables you to query CPU usage:

```
select *
from qpi.cpu_usage;
```

This library also enables you to get the information about historical CPU usage per Query Store intervals (available only in SQL server 2016+ and Azure SQL):

```
select start_time, execution_type_desc,
    tps =  sum(count_executions)/ min(interval_mi) /60,
    [cpu %] = ROUND(100 * sum(count_executions*cpu_time_s)/ min(interval_mi) /60 /(SELECT top 1 cpu_count FROM sys.os_sys_info)/*cores*/,1)
from qpi.db_query_plan_exec_stats_history
group by start_time, execution_type_desc
order by start_time desc
```

In addition this library enables you to easily find top queries or query plans that consumed most of the CPU time:

```
select top 10 *
from qpi.db_query_exec_stats_history
order by cpu_time_ms desc;

select top 10 *
from qpi.db_query_plan_exec_stats_history
order by cpu_time_ms desc
```

Ref this Microsoft blog: [Monitor CPU usage on SQL Server and Azure SQL](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql/monitor-cpu-usage-on-sql-server-and-azure-sql/ba-p/680777).

HTH.